# Angular ngx-editor outsource config from app.component.ts in other components.ts file

Tags: angular, components, ngx-editor

LiveDemo with Code see here
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-editor

In this project you can see in the document app.component.ts that the variable **editorConfig** contains the configuration of the editor.

I want to outsource this variable in a file, because I want to load a different configuration depending on the purpose of use.

If I create a componente, the page does not load. How can I create an ngx-config-component.ts which only contains the variable and how can I integrate this configuration afterwards?

Thank you very much for your help
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you need to separate this into a separate file but it would probably be best to use Angular's Dependency Injection mechanism. I made a fork on stackblitz as an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-editor-ecaqtx

I created a new service in the file **config.service.ts**:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigService {
  editorConfig = {
    editable: true,
    spellcheck: false,
    height: '10rem',
    minHeight: '5rem',
    placeholder: 'Type something. Test the Editor... ヽ(^。^)丿',
    translate: 'no'
  };
}
```

Registered it in the **app.module.ts**:

```
...
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpClientModule, NgxEditorModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [AppService, ConfigService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And then used it in the **app.component.ts**:

```
...
import { ConfigService } from './config.service';
...

  constructor(private _appService: AppService, private _configService: ConfigService) { 
    this.editorConfig = _configService.editorConfig;
  }
...
```

You can learn more about Angular's DI here: https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Another approach to the problem could be to pass the configuration as a **data** argument using the Angular Router so you could have different configurations using the same component, just on different routes. You can learn more here: https://angular.io/guide/router#router-state

Comment: Hello Matija Hrženjak, 

Thank you very much for your quick answer. It's great to know you're being helped. Why the hell does this guy have to have the configuration in his own file now? Doesn't make sense if you have components. 

Quite simply, we have about three standard configurations and the individual configurations, which are of course configured in the respective component. So that the app.component.ts is not unnecessarily filled, I want to outsource it. 

Thank you very much Matija for the fork and your invested time. 

salute
Christoph